# Switching off DEV mode in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using the `__DEV__` flag in a few places in my app. When this was an Expo app, I could switch from development mode to production mode pretty easily in the Metro bundler console. Now that I'm in a bare RN project (from `react-native init`), how can I switch `__DEV__` from true to false?

I tried putting `__DEV__ = false` in my code but it crashes the app.

Comment: If you open the menu in react-native apps (F2 or rage shake) and choose dev options, there is option to switch off dev mode along with other options like live reload

Comment: My options are Reload / Debug JS Remotely / Disable Live Reload / Start Systrace / Enable Hot Reloading / Change packager location / Toggle Inspector / Show Perf Monitor. I don't see Dev Options.